# Geb setting Values to Select issue

Tags: testing, selenium, spock, geb

I have troubles selecting a value from a List Box

```
<select name="max">
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50" selected="selected">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

In my Page I have:

```
class TableSectionModule extends Module {

    static base = { $('#runList') }

    static content = {
               tablePaginationSelect { $("select", name : "max") }
    }
}
```

I have used in my Spec all these calls:

```
runs.table.tablePaginationSelect = "100"
```

I have also tried this :

```
 runs.table.tablePaginationSelect.value('100')
```

But I have an exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.setSelected()V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.setSelected()V
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.selectByValue(Select.java:176)
    at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.setSelectValue(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:591)
    at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.setInputValue(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:548)
    at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.setInputValues_closure33(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:542)
    at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.setInputValues(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:541)
    at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.value(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:319)
    at geb.content.NavigableSupport.methodMissing(NavigableSupport.groovy:123)
    at geb.content.NavigableSupport.propertyMissing(NavigableSupport.groovy:141)
```

I am using Grails with Geb and here are the dependencies I am using :

```
dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'

        test("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion")
        test("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion")

        // You usually only need one of these, but this project uses both
        //test "org.codehaus.geb:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
        test "org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0"
        test "org.gebish:geb-spock:0.9.0"
        test "org.codehaus.geb:geb-spock:0.7.2"
        test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.0a7"

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.value('100')` syntax is correct. I used a sample gradle+geb (so no Grails, and so slightly different dependencies) project I had lying around, recreated your dropdown and your module, and was able to affect it with this syntax.

Try it without using the `Module`. Bypass it entirely and see what this gives you:

```
$('select' name:'max').value('100')
```

**Update**

Here's what I did to watch the changes happening on-screen (with a couple sanity check println's):

```
    def sel = $('select', name:'max')
    sel.size() == 1
    System.out.println(sel.getClass().name)
    System.out.println(sel)
    System.out.println(sel.value())
    Thread.sleep( 500 )
    sel.value ( "25"  )
    Thread.sleep( 500 )
    sel.value ( "50")
    Thread.sleep( 500 )
    sel.value ( "100")
    Thread.sleep( 500 )
    System.out.println(sel.value())
```

Also, once your test is complete, be sure to look at your test output. For myself, that's in `build/test-results`. Also, you can enable debug output on gradle: `gradlew build --debug`. It can be pretty helpful.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel for your response. I don't have the error anymore BUT nothing happens now...the select box didn't change. Any idea?

Comment: I updated my answer with some more suggestions. Hopefully something in there will shake out.

Comment: You could also consider updating your selenium dependency. Looks like you're using an alpha build (`2.0a7`). They're up to `2.33.0`.

Comment: hEY tHANKs Gabriel...I had to change the version of selenium support to 2.33.0..now it works with .value('100')